# Using dialog fragments for android API version 10 or below

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to show a created dialog for API version 10? I have changed my MainActivity's extension to FragmentActivity and getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager().

But then in my code snippet-

```
DuplicateColMessage duplicate_dialog =new DuplicateColMessage();
message="Column "+refinedcol[index].toUpperCase()+" already has data";
duplicate_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DROPBOX_SERVICE);
```

The duplicate_dialog.show() method complains about getSupportFragmentManager. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Make sure you're importing the `Fragment` class from the support package.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed a few spots with respect to that. Now its working.